# Is it possible to use R caret package to compute F-measure or G-mean for multiclass classification?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am interested in a multiple classes problem with imbalanced classes and I was rather happy with the `caret` package so far but, I have some practical issues with multiclass classification :

Is it possible to use another metric than accuracy and kappa, I don't find how to use F-measure or G-mean ? It seems that the only choice is between Accuracy and Kappa.

Here is an example of my code for some method and its relevant grid.

```
myControl <- trainControl(method='cv', number=5, classProbs = TRUE,sampling='up')

tune <- train(data.train[,-1],data.train[,1],tuneGrid=grid,method = method,metric= 'Kappa',trControl =myControl)
```

Comment: You questions might be better received on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @jeremycg my question has been closed for being off topic on cross validated...